# Firefox 47 Storage dev tool not working. Just me?

Tags: firefox, web-development, local-storage

**Original Question**

I've just upgraded Firefox to 47. No matter which site I go to, the `Storage` tab in dev tools always says "No data present for selected host".  Can anyone else replicate?

Go to [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/xlrah/), click `set item` then `get item`.  If the string "value" gets printed beneath the buttons, it means the item was successfully saved, then retrieved from sessionStorage. Now open the [Storage Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Storage_Inspector) in dev tools, select `sessionStorage` on the left, and see whether you can see the contents of storage.  I cannot even though there are contents there.

**Update June 17 2016**

Turns out the `Storage Inspector` within Firefox dev tools is broken if you select `Firefox settings >> Privacy >> History` to `Never remember history` or `Always use private browsing mode` (Firefox 47 32bit on Windows 7 64bit)

A fix appears to be in the works. I just installed Firefox 48 beta 1, and I no longer experience the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, they have broken it again on Firefox 52 for Windows. It only works on a random, undetermined basis.

Comment: Broken in Firefox Quantum.

Comment: Found another post on Stack Overflow that suggested removing the anchor fragment from the URL.  That solved it for me.

Comment: Erratic behavior in FF60. Some sites it displays that text, "No data present for selected host", while I'm sure they use cookies and cache. Other sites it works fine. Anchor fragment or not makes no difference.

Comment: Same problem in Firefox 84 on Ubuntu 16.04